# Modeling a 3 Blade Boat Propeller

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I  am trying to model a 3 blade boat propeller,  like the one shown in the image.  The image was taken from : http://sdshobbyusa.net

[image: 3 blade boat propeller, taken from http://sdshobbyusa.net]

I wasn't able to come up with a good way to model this propeller.  Does anyone know a good technique for modelling this hard surface model with good topology ?

Thank You!

---

I believe I have gotten the result that I desire. I still need to work on it a little to make it even better.  I did it because of PGmath 's help  (https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5705/pgmath) . Thank You!

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Model the blades straight and then use a simple deform modifier set to twist.  I am working on an answer now.

Comment: @PGmath You are denying speed answers like my a shot at this by calling out the method in the comments! D:

Comment: @PGmath I found that adding two simple deform modifiers, one for twist and one for bend, produced an OK result, but still not what I want. I am still unable to come up with a solution.

Comment: You could also try the extra objects addon, add a "Worm" and play with the settings.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms  Sorry, that's not what I intended to do.  I also didn't expect to take this long, it took me a while to get the topology of the fin good enough for deformation. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I would create a propeller like the one pictured.

First create a cylinder and extrude 3 of the faces out and model them into a propeller blade shape.  To get decent topology you can extrude along the edge of the blade and then use *Grid Fill* to fill it in.

[image]

Then just add a *Simple Deform* modifier and set it to *Twist*, I used an angle of 90°.

[image]

*Note: in the above example, instead of modeling all three fins at once, I deleted a third of the cylinder and used an Array modifier with the pivot point set to an empty rotated 120°.  That way I only had to model one blade.*