# How to create fan blades?

Tags: modeling

How do I make these fan blades for a jet engine? These are the blades I'm wanting to make. thanks[image: img]

Here is the **engine so far in** *blender*

[image: img]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40211/modeling-a-3-blade-boat-propeller and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86429/how-can-i-model-a-propeller-like-the-one-in-the-image

Comment: Here's 2 videos of how to do it... I would tell you how to do it in an answer but I can't right now... Hope these help. https://youtu.be/Oivgs0vzy8o is a traditional modeling method and https://youtu.be/YRgcXnd1Wl4 is a tutorial about the spin tool. The spin tool tutorial isn't specific to fan blades, but it could be a starting point for you if you decided to make it that way.